# Check IExplorer CSS3 compatibility automatically

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, compatibility

I have a big css style sheet and I would like to know if these styles are compatible with Internet Explorer 9.

I can verify each property but would be more efficient to analyze the entire file.

For example: linear gradient was only introduced in IE10, if I check linear gradient for IE9 it must alert me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest and most reliable way to achieve this is by using [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/)

In your scenario, you would use it by adding a fallback style for:

```
.no-cssgradients .gradient-fallback-class {
     /* Styles for non supported browsers */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I want analyze my css file to search IE9 incompatibilities. Modernizr can resolve problems, but I want check IE9 issues no resolve it automatically

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? What's the purpose of doing this? If a browser does not support something, you make a fall back for it. http://caniuse.com/ has an extensive list of what's supported.